# JS/jQuery : Best way to format/emphasise specific words in a textarea

Tags: javascript, formatting, textarea

I want to be able to detect text that has been entered and display this back to the user by changing the color of specific words in a textarea. Much the same way as in Facebook or Twitter when a user enters a @username tag into a posting.

I want that word to be highlighted to the user before the post is submitted so that they are aware the application has acknowledged it.

**What is the best way to achieve this kind of styling?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Textarea elements do not allow styling:

```
<textarea><b>Hi</b></textarea>
```

Will not bold the text, it will display the html as text. Instead, try the [contenteditable](http://devgrow.com/html5-contenteditable-attribute/) attribute.

Comment: Wow can't believe I have never heard about contenteditable before! It's even supported in old IE! Brilliant!